# Layout with form in angular Js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am a beginner in angular Js and need some help / pointers. I want to create an application (SPA). Every page of an application has a header bar and in that header bar, I have a form (like search bar) where a user can add data and search. But I am not being able to approach.

How should my approach be so that this header is present in any page of my app and I must be able to search in any page. How can this be done without code repetition? I mean I dont want to create a directive and call it in every page. I want to know if there is a proper way to do it?

The app should be like Quora where the input field for question is present in any page.

Request you to not downvote it as I am naive in Angular and need some good help.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: [This video](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/video-tutorial-angularjs-fundamentals-in-60-ish-minutes) is a little old, but it's a very good intro to Angularjs with a SPA.

Answer (score 0):

Search for `ui-router` and define some states for your application, basically you have a main states which hold header and footer, and sub states that are children of your main state.

your markup would be like this:

```
<header></header>

<ui-view></ui-view>

<footer></footer>
```

and the header can contain the search form, and all sub states are loaded in mains `<ui-view>`

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router)?

You could define a layout/root state whose template defines multiple named `ui-view`s.  The layout/root state could load the persisting elements (ex. the search input field) into one view, and child states could load the unique page content into another view.

ex. layout.html

```
<div class="layout">
    <div class="search" ui-view="search"></div>
    <div class="content" ui-view="content"></div>
</div>
```

ex. state configuration (in a module's `config()` function)

```
$stateProvider.state('root', {
  url: '',
  views: {
    'main': {
      templateUrl: 'layout.html'
    },
    'search@root': {
      template: '<input type="text" ng-model="search.input" />',
      controller: ['$scope', function($scope){
          $scope.search = {
              input: ''
          };
      }]
    }
  }
});

$stateProvider.state('root.page1', {
  views: {
    'content@root': {
      template: '<p>This is the first page.</p>',
    }
  }
})
.state('root.page2', {
  views: {
    'content@root': {
      template: '<p>This is the second page.</p>'
    }
  }
});
```

With that config, you would need to have in your main index.html: 
`<div ui-view="main"></div>`

[Plunker Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/vhE524bNqU8l560NKlIV?p=info)